# Suppress failed login message

Tags: ssh

When I don't have permission or log in with a wrong password
ssh prints "Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)."

Is there a way to configure SSH on the server to not emit anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is not from the server but from the client. You can suppress those messages with the -q option, like

```
ssh -q mvaldez@wintermute
```

Comment: I believe putting `LogLevel QUIET` into ssh_config will accomplish the same thing without requiring the use of a command line switch on every invocation.

Comment: You are right, the LogLevel option can do the same thing (in global ssh_config or personal .ssh/config).